# GNU Screen - any way to remove password when detached?

Tags: password, gnu-screen

Protecting a GNU screen session with a password is good security.  However, how does one remove the password if you need to share a session with a colleague?

I tried the following to clear it and got locked out (I ought to have tested it before detaching, but...):

```
ctrl+a :password clear
```

So, what exactly is the password set to in the above scenario?  Neither my previously set password nor my system account password would let me back in!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man screen`:

> password [crypted_pw]
>
> Present a **crypted** password in your ".screenrc" file and screen will ask for it, whenever someone attempts to resume a detached. This
>   is useful if you have privileged programs
>          running  under  screen  and  you want to protect your session from reattach attempts by another user masquerading as your uid (i.e.
>   any superuser.)  If no crypted password is
>          specified, screen prompts twice for typing a password and places its encryption in the paste buffer.  Default is `none', this
>   disables password checking.

`ctrl+a :password none` should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.  Tested and it works!  So, for the command I entered above, is there anyway I could have recovered from it?

Comment: The short answer is: No. If this would work, you'd be able to recover any other password protected screen session.

Comment: Well, I was only thinking from the perspective of my command above: the [cryted_pw] was 'clear' in my case and this is what I was pondering on whether there could have been a way to recover.  Oh well - at least I now know how to clear it!  Much appreciated!

Comment: The password is encrypted to secure the usage in files like ".screenrc", that is possibly readable by other users. So even if you know the encrypted password, `clear` in your case, you aren't able to easily recreate the clear text password from it.

Answer (score 0):

With most recent GNU Screen version 4.99.0 from github, you have the issue that you are forced to use a password re-attaching a session using 'screen -r'. I wrote a patch to workaround this issue in GNU Screen but you have to recompile your own GNU screen and apply my patch beforehand.

https://marcgloor.github.io/gnuscreenpatch.html

Comment: I suspect this is a bug; the behaviour was changed in [this commit](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/commit/?id=f0109ebc3c9bff61a2b79fc02d2cbc90989fbdda), notably removing the `password` command altogether, and enforcing passwords even when none are set.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it
[Disabling Gnu Screen Lock](https://www.pantz.org/software/screen/disabling_gnu_screen_lock_screen)

If you use ssh keys, and dont have a password, you may want to disable it.  There is a way to work-around and disable the lock program by adding the following to your .bashrc

`export LOCKPRG='/bin/true'`

If you exit and restart your screen sessions, next time you accidentally press ctrl+a x, it shouldn't lock any more.